# freeCodeCamp Title Case a Sentence Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm going through freeCodeCamp and am stuck on their "Basic Algorithm Scripting: Title Case a Sentence" challenge.  My code seems to output correctly, but freeCodeCamp is not passing me.  Any help or insights into what may be the cause of the issue would be much appreciated!

Here are their instructions:

- Return the provided string with the first letter of each word capitalized. Make sure the rest of the word is in lower case.
- For the purpose of this exercise, you should also capitalize connecting words like "the" and "of".
- titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") should return a string.
- titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") should return "I'm A Little Tea Pot".
- titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt") should return "Short And Stout".
- titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT") should return "Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout".

Here is my solution:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var strArray = str.split(' ');  // make string into an array
  var finalSentence = '';         // initialize variable for the final 'Title Cased' sentence
  
  // loop through each element in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    
    // get the length of each array element
    var strLength = strArray[i].length;
    
    // convert first letters of each word to upper-case
    finalSentence += strArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
      // convert remaining letters of each word to lower-case
      strArray[i].substring(1,strLength).toLowerCase() +
      // add space between words
      " ";
  }
  
  return finalSentence;
}

// string to test
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

My output reads "I'm A Little Tea Pot", which is what the instructions asked for.  The other inputs that the instructions asked me to test all output correctly as well...

Comment: Your solution is appending an extra space at the end of the sentence `"I'm A Little Tea Pot "`

Comment: Try... `finalSentence.substring(0, finalSentence.length - 1)` or `.trim()`

Comment: @spencer.sm thank you so much, I hadn't even thought of that last space being added at the end.  I used return finalSentence.trim() to take it off and that worked.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your journey into JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
   var ret = "";
   var upperCase = true;
   for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var chr = str.charAt(i);
    if(upperCase) {
      ret += chr.toUpperCase();
    }
    else{
      ret += chr.toLowerCase();
    }
    upperCase = chr == " ";
  }
  console.log(ret);
}
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt");
titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT");
```

Answer (score 0):

First I explain what is the wrong in your code,

In your code,

```
finalSentence += strArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArray[i].substring(1,strLength).toLowerCase() + " ";
```

In the last, you add " " to add space between words. Thus, after every word, it will add " ". So, you can get the output for `titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");`
like this, "I'm A Little Tea Pot " not "I'm A Little Tea Pot". See, there is an additional " " (space) in your coding output.

You can add " " like this,

```
finalSentence += strArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArray[i].substring(1,strLength).toLowerCase();

    if(i < strArray.length - 1){
      finalSentence += " ";
    }
```

This is another easy way to do this challenge,

```
function titleCase(str) {
    let strArr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
          strArr[i] = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].slice(1);
      }
      return strArr.join(' ');
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Good Luck!. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  const arr = [];
  let addUpper = true;
  
  str.split("").forEach(e =>{
    if(addUpper){
    arr.push( e.toUpperCase());
    addUpper = false;
    }else{
        arr.push(e.toLowerCase());
    }   
    if(e === " "){
      addUpper = true;
    }
    
  })
  return(arr.join(""));
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: It would be good if you could give a brief description of how this works.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.